# Dequeuing in batches

Tags: rabbitmq

When dequeuing from RabbitMQ it seems that the entire queue of messages is taken into memory and then processed, a minimal example can be the tutorial at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html.
Giving for example 1000 messages, they are taken all together in the event Received and the event handler manages 1000 messages: instead, I would to take 100 messages at time in order to divide the message consuming among 2 or more servers using a load balancer as HAProxy.
Is it possible or the only possibility is in the event handler make a manual round robin to other servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [the prefecth](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) to decide how many messages you want to download to the client.

> instead, I would take 100 messages at a time in order to divide the message consuming among 2 or more servers.

it is what is explained [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html) of "Fair dispatch" section, in your case you have to set the prefetch to 100 instead of 1 and attach more consumers to the same queue.